# Setting up TPM2 in Ubuntu: tpm2-abrmd error "insufficient buffer to get handle"

Tags: encryption, tpm

I am trying to setup an encrypted drive using the TPM2.0 module on a NUC7i5 on a new installation of Ubuntu server 18.04.

I compiled from sources and installed tpm2-tss (1.3.0), tpm2-abrmd (1.2.0) and tpm2-tools (3.0.2), and I tested some of the tpm2_* utilities and they seem to work. I also installed clevis v10.

I generated a secret using `tpm2_getrandom 32 -o secret.key`, and then tried to encrypt the secret using the TPM using the following command:

```
cat secret.key | sudo clevis encrypt tpm2 '{"pcr_ids":"7","pcr_bank":"sha256"}' > secret.jwe
```

When I do that however, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:
CreatePrimary Failed ! ErrorCode: 0x9a2

ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_createprimary
Creating TPM2 primary key failed!
```

When checking the status of the tpm2-abrmd service (`systemctl status tpm2-abrmd.service`), I get this error:

```
tpm2-abrmd[1308]: tpm2_response_get_handle: insufficient buffer to get handle
```

I tried different options for the clevis encryption, tried different ways to generate the secret, but I still can't figure out what the issue is.

The TPM module is a SLB9665 from Infineon Technologies.

I tried with and without taking ownership of the TPM, and always with a clear TPM every time.

Has anyone ran into that issue?

Comment: I'm confused because the `tpm2_createprimary` [options that clevis is using](https://github.com/latchset/clevis/blob/4d3b588f9402085beb214315269e1590514f593b/src/clevis-encrypt-tpm2#L109) don't seem to match the [available options](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_createprimary.1.md). Can you post links to everything you have installed?

Comment: From what I can see, the options do match, the only option that is not in the man of tpm2_createprimary is -Q, which is a [common option](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/3.0.2/man/common/options.md) to all TPM2 tools to run quiet

Comment: Hierarchy is supposed to be `-a` not `-H`, no?

Comment: Not for tpm2-tools [v3.0.2](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/3.0.2/man/tpm2_createprimary.1.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the issue was that I shouldn't have taken ownership of the TPM.
After resetting the TPM, the clevis command works.